# How to use a Yubikey NEO (or any OpenPGP card or GnuPG in general) to sign X.509 CSRs?

Tags: certificate-authority, x.509, smartcard, yubikey, gnupg

Since the Yubikey NEO can be used as an OpenPGP card (see [here](https://www.yubico.com/2012/12/yubikey-neo-openpgp)) with three 2048 bit RSA keys, I thought about creating a CA from one of its public keys. Since the private key cannot be extracted (according to that article at least, anyway that's the point of using it first place), I can't simply use `openssl ca -inkey ...` to sign certificate requests.

Now before I go about trying to manually generate the string that is to be signed for a valid certificate and use `gpg` (which can use the Yubikey NEO) to do so, is there an easier way to do so, e.g. via `gpgsm` or another `openssl` parameter?

Comment: Here are some example scripts that make this work: https://github.com/jymigeon/gpgsm-as-ca

Comment: @Luc Great, I'll have a look at them :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

GnuPG 2.1.0beta2 supports signing certificates in batch mode:

> Support X.509 certificate creation.
>
> Using "gpgsm --genkey" allows the creation of a self-signed
>   certificate via a new prompt.
>
> Using "gpgsm --genkey --batch" should allow the creation of arbitrary
>   certificates controlled by a parameter file.  An example parameter
>   file is
>
> ```
> Key-Type: RSA
> Key-Length: 1024
> Key-Grip: 2C50DC6101C10C9C643E315FE3EADCCBC24F4BEA
> Key-Usage: sign, encrypt
> Serial: random
> Name-DN: CN=some test key
> Name-Email: foo@example.org
> Name-Email: bar@exmaple.org
> Hash-Algo: SHA384
> not-after: 2038-01-16 12:44
> ```
>
> This creates a self-signed X.509 certificate using the key given by
>   the keygrip and using SHA-384 as hash algorithm.  The keyword
>   signing-key can be used to sign the certificate with a different key.
>   See sm/certreggen.c for details.

(source: [Commit message](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commit;h=28c157b55cf6db6b6988def5c9512e388c512b10), also [NEWS](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=NEWS;h=1255b34863e869ab33fa5f27df59bc971b07cdf3;hb=28c157b55cf6db6b6988def5c9512e388c512b10))

---

I got it working, here are the steps involved (**Do not do this on your production system!**)

- You need libksba >= 1.3 (get it [here](ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/libksba/))
- Get the 2.1 beta 3 from ftp://ftp.gnupg.org/gcrypt/gnupg/unstable/
- Create a key which will be used for signing (that's the CA key which in the real application will never leave your Open PGP card / Yubikeo NEO) - if you want to use a password (recommended if you still want to use this in production), remember that you must setup `pinentry` to work without your console, i.e. either use a graphical one or use `screen` and set `GPG_TTY` to the other `tty` when you use `pinentry-curses` (note to self: when the prompt shows, hit enter once to actually activate it and not use your passphrase as a cleartext command...)
- Create a key which will used for the certificate (I don't know if you can also use gpgsm to sign other CSRs, you'll probably have to extract the public key in that case)
- (I used one main key for the CA and its subkey for the certificate)
- Obtain the Key-Grips: Either check the filenames in `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` and deduce it from the creation date, or run `gpg2 -K --with-key-data`, search for the line containing the key ID (not the entire fingerprint, that is somehow split up and scrambled) and check the next line starting with `grp:::`
- Create a self-signed CA certificate with the following batch input:

> ```
> Key-Type: RSA
> Key-Grip: E9CE7D421500AD119A4E308BC34317710AA2D57F #(replace with CA keygrip)
> Key-Usage: cert
> Serial: random
> Name-DN: CN=Test Root CA
> Hash-Algo: SHA512
> not-after: 2038-01-16 12:44
> ```

and run `gpgsm --gen-key --batch --output CA.crt < batchinputfile`

- Create a signed certificate with the following batch input:

> ```
> Key-Type: RSA
> Key-Grip: E308BC34317710AA2D57FE9CE7D421500AD119A4 #(replace with keygrip)
> Key-Usage: sign, encrypt
> Serial: random
> Name-DN: CN=Tester
> Issuer-DN: CN=Test Root CA
> Hash-Algo: SHA512
> not-after: 2038-01-16 12:44
> Signing-Key: E9CE7D421500AD119A4E308BC34317710AA2D57F #(replace with CA keygrip)
> Authority-Key-Id: E9CE7D421500AD119A4E308BC34317710AA2D57F #(replace with CA keygrip)
> ```

and run `gpgsm --gen-key --batch --output cert.crt < batchinputfile`

Some more information on possible batch parameters can be found [here (incomplete doc)](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=doc/gpgsm.texi;h=bdb03783e0f4441408b94d8f0045aed91b739e06;hb=HEAD#l962) and in [certreqgen.c](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=sm/certreqgen.c;hb=HEAD#l235); you should also manually include `basicConstraints` via `Extension`, which is by default omitted if you specify an Issuer-DN, as can be seen [in the source](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=sm/certreqgen.c;hb=HEAD#l1025).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is feasible. Frankly speaking, gpgsm is really not good at managing general purpose X.509 certificates. Some behavior is implicit. (e.g. keyUsage based on cert/sign/...) The supported keywords are rather limited (e.g. no IPaddress SAN). Of course one can compose desired X.509 extension and pass to gpgsm via `Extension: <oid> C|c|N|n <hex>`. It's just tedious and duplicate what openssl is capable of. And I ran into a bug when signing RSA leaf with ECC CA. (patch sent, no idea when it will get merged)

Comment: Current gpgsm implementation requires private key of leaf certificate. You're out of luck if you only have CSR to be signed. This restriction can be lifted by convert the public key to S-expression and put it under `~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/<KeyGrip>.key`.

Comment: To reuse an existing CA instead of generate a new one, `pem2openpgp` can be used to convert private key to gpg.

Comment: I posted my best effort at https://gist.github.com/zhangyoufu/b4068a48af1ca78a103d3b00c7c9a4c5, for reference.

Comment: @youfu Sounds great, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

OpenSSL can theoretically use PKCS#11 modules through a specific [engine add-on](https://github.com/OpenSC/engine_pkcs11). But there is [no PKCS#11 module for YubiKey yet](http://www.yubico.com/2012/12/yubikey-neo-openpgp/#comment-1089). The comment alludes to something called "[scute](http://www.scute.org/)" which appears to be a PKCS#11 module which wraps around GnuPG -- as such, it *may* be compatible with the OpenPGP implementation for the YubiKey.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Scute seems to only enable Firefox (or other NSS-using software) for client authentication, but OpenSC seems to support OpenPGP cards (don't have one yet to test this though): https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/wiki/OpenPGP-card

Comment: Hi, have you managed to test OpenSC on Yubikey NEO? How did it go?

Comment: @Ahmed In case you were asking me, I didn't come around to obtaining a Yubikey NEO so far, though it's still somewhere on my list...

Comment: openssl+libp11 works smoothly for me. Tested with YubiKey 4 (openpgp) on macOS.